# ABP Framework, how to get identity custom properties from IIdentityUserRepository

Tags: abp

I have successfully add new custom property as IsPartner in identity. now i have to get list of all users those are marked as Partner, i tried to get by _repository.GetListAsync but it doesn't have my new property.

```
 public class UtilityAppService : CrmAppService, IUtilityAppService
    {
       private readonly IIdentityUserRepository _repository;
        public UtilityAppService(IIdentityUserRepository identityUserRepository) {
          _repository = identityUserRepository;
        // _repository.GetListAsync() it doesn't have custom properties. 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have created the mapping in the YourProjectNameEfCoreEntityExtensionMappings.cs class ?  Or do you store the custom  properties in the ExtraProperties column ?

Comment: `I have successfully add new custom property` How did you verify this?